# How do I create a "folder" for items based on a "category" in the database?

Tags: database, vuejs2, mapping

I am using Vue with Laravel and trying to create a page that shows a list of items based on a category. Each item is stored in the database with a "category" column. I want to be able to display only the categories (no repeats) that then could have maybe a dropdown that shows all items with that category.

For example, if these were objects, they would look like this:

```
{
   name: "Car",
   category: "Red"
},
{
   name: "Car2",
   category: "Blue"
},
{
   name: "Motorcycle",
   category "Red"
},
{
   name: "Motorcycle2",
   category: "Blue"
}
```

If the data were like this, I would want to display two options, Red and Blue, and under both I would want to show their respective objects. For example:

Red: Car, Motorcycle
Blue: Car2, Motorcycle2

I've tried using JavaScript to help "stack" them in a way when mapping over. I've tried selecting only unique values from the database.